# Update value using jquery and contenteditable="true"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onchange, contenteditable

I have this HTML:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1">Deluxe Junior Suite</td>
          <td contenteditable="true" class="update_rate" data-id="46">0.00</td>
        </tr>
```

I want to update price using jquery when user change value in table cell so I write:

```
$('.update_rate').on('input', (e) => {

  var price = $(this).html();
    var id = $(this).data('id');

var data = {
                    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    id: id,
                    price: price,
                    
    };
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/update_rate',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                      if (data.status == '200') {
                            console.log('updated'); 
                          }                      
                    },
                    error: function(data)
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });

  });
```

but I got an error:

**jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of null**

How to solve that? What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), as they cannot have a `this` value bound to them. Use a normal [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) instead.

```
$('.update_rate').on('input', function(e){

  var price = $(this).html();
    var id = $(this).data('id');

var data = {
                    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    id: id,
                    price: price,
                    
    };
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/update_rate',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                      if (data.status == '200') {
                            console.log('updated'); 
                          }                      
                    },
                    error: function(data)
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });

  });
```